# Random Intercept Correlation (lmer)

Tags: r, correlation, lme4-nlme

I'm fitting a mixed model with a nesting structure that produces a correlation in the random intercept. I'm having a difficult time understanding the correlation coefficient and obtaining the correlation matrix for each individual (which might not be possible in R but seems possible in SAS?).

Here is an example model:

```
    library(lme4)

    dat <- sleepstudy

    fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days|Subject), data = dat)
    summary(fit)
```

The output produces the following:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 612.09   24.740       
          Days         35.07    5.922   0.07
 Residual             654.94   25.592       
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  251.405      6.825   36.84
Days          10.467      1.546    6.77

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Days -0.138
```

There is a random effect correlation of 0.07 between Days and the Intercept (reaction time). I'm taking this to mean that as Days (of sleep deprivation) increases so does reaction time. Because I have the subject nested in the day, does this mean that this is the "repeated measures correlation" as detailed by [Roy](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.200510192/abstract)? I'm not 100% certain that it can be interpreted in this fashion because in the attached article, the author is using the actual correlation matrices for each individual subject (in SAS), which I can't seem to reproduce in R.

Has anyone worked with repeated measures correlation in this fashion using R?

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I can certainly post it over to CrossValidated as well. RE: Roy, what she did was create a pearson correlation by calling the variance-covariance matrices of the random effects for each individual. That is the part of my question specific to stack overflow, I guess. I'm not aware of there being a way to do this in R as it seems like it is SAS specific?

Comment: I had originally attempted to re-create the actual analysis from Roy here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242931/pearsons-correlation-from-a-mixed-model) but was not successful.

Comment: my problem is that without spending quite a bit of time reading the Roy article, I'm not even sure why there should be *distinct* variance-covariance matrices for each individual; as I understand it, there should be a single V-C matrix that applies to all individuals

Comment: Yea, it's a good question and that is what I can't figure out. She called it a "new" method. This is why I'm trying to better understand how to interpret the correlation in the random effects because maybe that will help me. Though I can't seem to find any articles or books that talk explicitly about it. It seems like it gets glossed over. If there are any resources you could recommend I'd be all ears! Thanks!